Finding the least kth Taylor polynomial to approximate ln(2) within 0.001
I was asked to find the least integer $k$ such that the $kth$ Taylor polynomial of $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$ approximates $\ln(2)$ within $0.001$. I thought I had the answer, which I show below:
$$R_{k}(1) \leq 0.001$$ where $R_{k}(1) = \frac{M}{(k+1)!}$ with $M$ as the maximum value of the $|f^{k+1}(x)|$ on the interval $[0,1]$. I thought $$|f^{k+1}(x)|=\frac{k!}{(1+x)^{k+1}},$$ so the maximum value is obtained when $x=0$, or $$M=k!$$ If this is true, then $R_{k}(1)=\frac{1}{k+1}$, so $$\frac{1}{k+1}\leq 0.001$$ and $k\geq999$, so the least $k$ should be 999. However, when checking with desmos and wolfram alpha, both seem to give a minimum $k$ as $500$. What went wrong in my solution?

You wrote that $R_k(1)=\dfrac{M}{(k+1)!}$ but we only have an inequality. Your idea would only show that the least k is smaller than 999.

(This replicates some previous work of mine.)
We can show that
if $0 < t \le 1$
then
$\begin{array}\\
\ln(1+t)-\sum_{k=1}^{n} (-1)^{k-1}\dfrac{t^{k}}{k}
&=(-1)^{n}\int_0^t\dfrac{x^{n}}{1+x}dx\\
&=(-1)^{n}E_n(t)\\
\end{array}
$
where
$E_n(t)
=\int_0^t\dfrac{x^{n}}{1+x}dx
$.
$\begin{array}\\
E_n(t)
&=\int_0^t\dfrac{x^{n}}{1+x}dx\\
&<\int_0^tx^{n}dx\\
&=\dfrac{t^{n+1}}{n+1}\\
\text{and}\\
E_n(t)
&=\int_0^t\dfrac{x^{n}}{1+x}dx\\
&>\int_0^t\dfrac{x^{n}}{1+t}dx\\
&=\dfrac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)(1+t)}\\
\text{so}\\
E_n(1)
&<\dfrac{1}{n+1}\\
\text{and}\\
E_n(1)
&>\dfrac{1}{2(n+1)}\\
\text{so if}\\
E_n(1)
&=c\\
\text{then}\\
\end{array}
$
$\dfrac{1}{2(n+1)}
\le c
\le \dfrac{1}{n+1}
$
or
$\dfrac1{2c}-1 \le n \le \dfrac1{c}-1
$.
For $c=.001$
this is
$499 \le n \le 999$.
Looks like the lower bound
is more accurate.

$u_n =\displaystyle \left|\ln(2)-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k}\right|    $
We can show that:
$u_n =\displaystyle \int_0^1\dfrac{x^n}{1+x} dx    $
Then:
$\displaystyle u_n-\dfrac{1}{2n} = \int_0^1 \left(\dfrac{x^n}{1+x} -\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{2} \right)dx =\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^n-x^{n-1}}{2(1+x)}dx <0 $
We have also:
$\displaystyle u_n = \left\lbrack\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \dfrac{1}{x+1} \right\rbrack_0^1 +\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} \dfrac{1}{(x+1)^2}dx >\dfrac{1}{2(n+1)}$
So:
$ \dfrac{1}{2(n+1)} < u_n < \dfrac{1}{2n} $
$...   $
